# C# says invalid certificate error on Linux Centos

Tags: mongodb

We are using C# driver "Mongo Db driver 2.9.2" in C# API(.NET core version 2.2) deployed in Linux CentOS to connect to Mongo server 4.2 deployed on Linux CentOS. TLS is enabled on Mongo and self signed certificates are used. Same code and certificates are working from Windows machine but on Linux we are getting following error. Please suggest:

A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : \"1\", ConnectionMode : \"Automatic\", Type : \"Unknown\", State : \"Disconnected\", Servers : [{ ServerId: \"{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : \"Unspecified/ServerName\" }\", EndPoint: \"Unspecified/ip-ServerName\", State: \"Disconnected\", Type: \"Unknown\", HeartbeatException: \"MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could resolve this by using server certificate instead of wild card certificate.